# How to test SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, ios8, xcode6

iOS 8 will be rolling out soon. We have Xcode beta 6 atm, but still cannot find any docs on **how to properly test Family Sharing** (or did I miss something?). My question is how to properly setup Sandbox with parent/child? I tried to make it work in beta 1 without joy.

Any hints guys?

**Update:**

Two related stories on Apple Developer Forum:

1. How to create a children sandbox account on iTunes Connect?(https://devforums.apple.com/message/1030357#1030357)
2. Testing "Ask to Buy" in sandbox (https://devforums.apple.com/message/1005569#1005569)

Comment: I have done a bit of research and unfortunately there is no documentation or methodology to test this I have found.

Answer (score 25):

I've made a little headway on this topic, so thought I'd report in. Plus, I've found an apparent bug, which I've reported to Apple.

What I've done is the following:

1) Create a parent test (sandbox) account in iTunes Connect, and create a child test account. These are really just two test accounts in iTunes Connect. Call them P and C for parent and child.

2) With both accounts, go to https://appleid.apple.com and change their year for their age. iTunes Connect doesn't let you do this. For some reason, the process with family sharing doesn't work unless ages do have a year. I've found that you have to do the selection twice on the year list at https://appleid.apple.com. Odd. I set my P as older (some adult age) and my C as younger.

3) On one apple device (my iPhone, running iOS8), I setup family sharing under Settings > iCloud for the P account. I'm signed into iTunes on this device with my real iTunes Apple Id (which has my payment info).

4) I then invite my C apple id to be part of my family, under Settings > iCloud.

5) I accept the invitation from P (on my iPad, also running iOS8), which involves signing into the iCloud on that other device as C.

6) On my iPhone, I turn on "Ask To Buy" for the C family member.

Now, I'm ready to try a test purchase as C on my sandboxed app. After I go through the regular process in my app's store I get the following alert:

[image]

when I tap on "Ask", I get the next alert:

[image]

Now, I've tried two options, with separate purchases. I've tried the "OK" option, which should send a notification to the P account. I have yet to receive such a notification on my P account (still signed into iCloud as that on my iPad).

I've also tried the "Approve in Person" option on the "child"s iPad. I use the P account, and I enter in that if on the next alert:

[image]

I get no error after that, so it would seem the Approve In Person worked, but I have yet to have that purchase convert to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased state. All of the deferred purchases are still in the payment queue of the app, each with the state SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred. When I restart the app, the state of each purchase, still in the queue, is deferred.

Next, I wondered if there was some problem with the particular test iTunes account for C, so I made a second child account, call that C2, and tried to establish it as a child under P on my iPhone. However, I run into a further problem there. I get the alert (on the iPad), when I try to accept the invitation to be a family member under P for C2:

[image]

To me, this limitation on iCloud account shouldn't apply to test accounts. This is the apparent bug I've reported to Apple.

So, in summary, I'm not yet 100% convinced that my SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred implementation is working. We shall see if Apple gets back to me.

Comment: Do you know what happens if the user buys a product several times with Ask To Buy? Will iOS handle the case and report that the purchase is already waiting for approval? Or do I have to check whether the product approval has been deferred and disable the purchase button?

Comment: another question i have is: should you finish the transaction when the deferred state comes in? i assume not but i couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: For your first question, yes. You shouldn't need to disable your purchase button. But I had to be clever in my purchase observer delegate. If *all* of the transactions are deferred, I infer that the delegate method was not caused directly by my UI. For your second question. It appears you never finish these transactions. See WWDC talk 303.

Comment: Step 2 was helpful. I'm having a same problem. P device is not getting any notification so can't complete the purchase. Any further progress?

Comment: No, no more progress. I'm still not sure if my implementation works. I'll need to try it in a production release. No word back yet from Apple on the bug report.

Comment: Chris, thanks for your detailed guide of steps.  Were you able to get the implementation working on the production release?  

Also, are you sure we don't need to finish the deferred transactions?

Comment: Hey guys, I found two links that was very helpful.
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1063364#1063364
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1091572#1091572

Comment: It will be another month or so before I can test this in a production release. I'll try to post an update this then.

Comment: Thanks @CLDev for those links. The Apple rep is pretty glib about how easy it is for one to get the deferred state processing implemented and working correctly! I haven't found much about IAPs easy!

Comment: I managed to follow your guide (great work +1) but as you described we never get the request on the parent device.

Comment: Hi guys, any news on production iOS? Did you finally succeed?

Comment: Not yet for me. I've had some delays in getting my next app version out.

Comment: Do you know which `SKError` the observer receives when the deferred purchase is rejected?

Comment: I don't know-- I should be just a few days away from being able to test this with a production app and will report back.

Comment: I have a "Family information is not available" in iCloud (Simulator). Also I need to give valid credit card information even for the test parent account to create a Family?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPrince I followed your answer but still not receiving any notification on the parent to give permission for the purchase. Any advice?

Comment: In production? Or in the sandbox?

Comment: Another piece, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187148/deferred-transactions/26371545#26371545

Comment: Just curious if there was ever any resolution to this.. it has indeed been quite some time with no final words on it. The links from CLDev no longer work, the linked question just sums up with 'Dont finish this until you get a FAIL or SUCCESS message'.

Comment: Is there a resolution to this yet? I saw the 2017 WWDC where the guy slightly touches the topic and mentions using a mutable payment object but that's about it. Is there really a good way to test this?

Answer (score 7):

From iOS 8.3 there is a new flag available for SKPayment: `simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox`.

So in case you need to test SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred state you initialize 
new `SKMutablePayment` and set `simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox = YES`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS83APIDiffs/frameworks/StoreKit.html

**PS. WARNING: folks complain that this API doesn't work properly (see comments)**

Comment: Great! Will try it on a days :)!

Comment: I excited to hear about this, until seeing that Apple hasn't given expected behavior for this new flag!! Have you submitted a bug report on this to Apple? I.e., the lack of documentation on this new property?

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work for me under iOS 9.1 SDK. Here is a reference to [question at Apple Dev Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5703) (with no answer, yet).

Comment: 2023 and this still does not work at all. simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox does not trigger the deferred state, so your app will just be stuck in "awaiting payment update" mode. Great, Apple.

Answer (score 5):

**iOS 9.2.1, Xcode 7.2.1, ARC enabled**

Confirmed!  The `simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox` property does not cause the payment queue observer to register the `SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred` state.  Instead, it just process the payment and the observer registers the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state.

```
SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment
   paymentWithProduct:productUserRequested];

payment.simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox = true;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

The only test I was able to perform was to call my method for the deferred payment when the observer registered the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state instead of my usual method and not call:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

This persists the transaction upon app. termination, and gives you the ability to test the user not completing the purchase (e.g. loss of reception during final stages of purchasing) and deferred purchase.  This is assuming your purchasing method passes a deferred parameter, as described in ***Listing 4-2  Responding to transaction statuses*** in [In App Purchasing Guide: Delivering Products](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW4).  Here is what the method would look like:

To simulate hung up purchasing:

```
[self showTransactionAsInProgress:transaction deferred:NO];
```

To simulate deferred:

```
[self showTransactionAsInProgress:transaction deferred:YES];
```

Note: Upon app. restart, the Apple in app. purchase mechanism will ask for your credentials if you did not process any other payments for the credentials, uninstalled the app., or signed out of "iTunes and App Stores" in "Settings".  Also, if you tap "Cancel" here, then the transaction will not fail, because the payment queue observer will keep registering the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state.

**UPDATE 3/4/2016:**

I found this suggestion from Apple which might prove to be helpful, it is a fancy way of doing what I suggested:

> **Test an Interrupted Transaction**
>
> Set a breakpoint in your transaction queue observer’s
>   paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method so you can control whether it
>   delivers the product. Then make a purchase as usual in the test
>   environment, and use the breakpoint to temporarily ignore the
>   transaction—for example, by returning from the method immediately
>   using the thread return command in LLDB.
>
> Terminate and relaunch your app. Store Kit calls the
>   paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method again shortly after launch;
>   this time, let your app respond normally. Verify that your app
>   correctly delivers the product and completes the transaction.

Hope this helps!  Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

When creating child account according to [Chris Prince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27367749/1402846), make sure you set its "age" between 13 and 18 years old. If you set it to be less than 13, you can't verify its age (even if you add credit card to your P account). If it's above 18 - option to enable Ask to buy is gone. Spent hours trying to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Also, you need to create C account via iTunes Connect, not via "Create child's account" option in family sharing screen.

Wish I could comment, but since I don't have 50 reputation points, I have to create a separate answer.

Comment: Giving a +1 since when you use a sandbox account to sign into "itunes" it pretty much bricks that sandbox account for future testing. Using it inside of IAP works, because IAP does a "fallback" into sandbox so you get sandbox on the login retry.

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out it would appear that the sandbox environment does not support the parent child relationship so the messages will not be sent when the accounts in question are setup as mentioned in the answer by @ChrisPrince.

The article I dug up can be found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/38561#117143

The snippet of importance from the answer by the apple staff member is

> With regards to Ask-To-Buy support, there is no support for this function in the Sandbox. “Ask to Buy” is not an API implementation, but a support process implemented by iTunesConnect which requires StoreKit interaction with a specific iTunes account. This support only exists in the production environment. For this process to work in the sandbox environement, ITC would need to implement for test accounts to refer to other accounts to grant approval for purchases.

The rest of the article highlights the guidelines and flows for Ask to Buy support but testing must be done in the production environment where the child/parent account relationship is active.

Comment: Mainly because this is a newer response and tallies with my initial investigation adding a +1, and which also tallies with @Raimundas answer

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The only way to test this is the production environment.  Apple seriously????

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 12, there is a way to mock in-app purchases that gives you much more control. You can set up IAPs completely in Xcode without ever having to go to App Store Connect. And you can manage them instead of creating multiple sandbox accounts and starting over again and again. This is very helpful for testing the deferred transaction state.

## Create a mock in-app purchase

1. Add a new `.storekit` file by going to File > New File > StoreKit Configuration file
   [image]
2. Click the Add button and select whichever type of in-app purchase you need
   [image]
3. Give your IAP a name, product ID, price, etc.
   [image]

## Point your app to your new mock in-app purchase

1. Select your app's scheme and click Edit Scheme
   [image]
2. Under Run, select the Options tab. Under StoreKit Configuration, select the .storekit file you just created. This will point your app to your .storekit file instead of Apple servers
   [image]

## View/manage your transactions

1. Run your app and in Xcode navigate to Debug > StoreKit > Manage Transactions
   [image]
2. Complete your transaction in your app
   [image]
3. Observe that your transaction is now visible in Xcode's StoreKit debug window
   [image]

## Test deferred transactions

1. Select your .storekit file, and click Editor > Enable Ask to Buy
   [image]
2. You probably have something like this in your code:

   ```
   SKPaymentQueue.default().add(SKPayment(product: skProduct))
   ```

- Comment it out and add this instead:

  ```
  let mutablePayment = SKMutablePayment(product: skProduct)
  mutablePayment.simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox = true
  SKPaymentQueue.default().add(mutablePayment)
  ```

3. Build the app and complete the transaction once more. You should now see the "Ask Permission" prompt
   [image]
4. After asking permission, you can approve or deny the transaction by selecting it and clicking the Approve or Deny buttons
   [image]

Comment: I don't know how to display the product this way. The method that would normally fetch the product from AppStore fails, and I don't have an SKProduct without it.