# What should the app do in response to a deferred SKPaymentTransaction?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have in-app purchases in my app, and new to iOS 8 are "deferred" transactions, partially described in [a tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html)

I understand what it does and that I need to not block the UI, and update my UI to reflect that the transaction state is deferred. But what am I supposed to place in the method `-(void)transactionDeferred:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction` to disregard the transaction for the time being?

Do I only have update the UI? Also what should the content of the UI be? Do I need to replace the price label with something like "Your purchase is deferred"? I don't think there is a way to test this, at least I haven't seen anything about it with my sandbox test account. If there was a way to go through the process and see how it works, it would make a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What I am doing is:

1. Stopping indicator animation
2. Activating *buy* and *restore* buttons
3. Showing an alert:

> **Waiting For Approval**
>   Thank you! You can continue to use Altershot while your purchase is pending an approval from your parent.

I watched WWDC 14 video. Apple says you should't block UI and allow to click on buy button again. I think we need this in case parent miss alert, so child can send one more.

What I know is that we **should not**  call following method for deferred transactions:

`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];`

Comment: the documentation says "Your application should call finishTransaction: only after it has successfully processed the transaction and unlocked the functionality purchased by the user." which indicates you don't need to call finishTransaction when the state is SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred.

Comment: you should wait for FAIL or PURCHASED. you should now call finishTransaction in deferred.

Comment: Is it normal that during Xcode testing pressing Ask or Cancel sets the transaction's state to deferred?

Comment: @SleepNot “Cancel” shouldn’t defer it, it should cancel. I’m not sure it’s normal.

Answer (score 3):

The code bellow will allow you to check if the product ID you want to sell is in deferred mode. Use it to update the UI accordingly.

```
if ([[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions count] > 0) {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
        if ([@"your.product.id"  isEqualToString:transaction.payment.productIdentifier]) {
            if (transaction.transactionState ==  SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred) {
                // update UI that you are still waiting for parent approval. You'll get "PURCHASED" if parent approved or "FAILD" if parent declined or 24 hours passed since request.
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```