# PaymentQueue firing before ProductRequest

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

I have below code for my IAP. Intend is to reuse code for different IAPs.

```
// Purchase Asked
func purchaseAsked(prodIncoming: String) {

    println("inside purchase Asked")

    switch prodIncoming {
    case "multiTaps":
        prod = "CricketCrazy.UnlockMultiTaps"
    case "ads":
        prod = "CricketCrazy.AdRemoval"
    case "5000Taps":
        prod = "CricketCrazy.TapBlast.5000"
    case "12000Taps":
        prod = "CricketCrazy.TapBlast.12000"
    case "30000Taps":
        prod = "CricketCrazy.TapBlast.30000"
    case "70000Taps":
        prod = "CricketCrazy.TapBlast.70000"
    case "200000Taps":
        prod = "CricketCrazy.TapBlast.200000"
    default:
        break
    }

    println("going to add observer")
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

    println("going to getProductionInfo")

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        //canDoIap = true
        println("canDoIap = true")
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: prod)

        println("productID: \(productID)")
        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID)

        println("request: \(productsRequest)")
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()

    } else {
        println("canDoIap = false")
        //canDoIap = false
    }

}

func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    println("inside productRequest function")
    let products = response.products
    if products.count != 0
    {
        product = products[0] as SKProduct
    }

    switch restoring {
    case false:
        println("restoring = false")
        let payment:SKPayment = SKPayment (product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
        break
    case true:
        println("restoring = true")
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        break
    default:
        break
    }

}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        println("inside paymentQueue Fuction")
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                println(".Purchased")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction (transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                postPurchaseActions(true)
                break
            case .Failed:
                println(".Failed")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction (transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                postPurchaseActions(false)
                break
            case .Restored:
                println(".Restored")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                if consumeable == false {
                    postPurchaseActions(true)
                }
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that as you can see from log below. It fires paymentQueue even before it reaches the productRequest and tries to restore IAP (twice). It even tries to restore consumable IAPs.
What am I doing wrong. Is there a better way to handle multiple IAPs in swift projects.

```
inside purchase Asked
going to add observer
going to getProductionInfo
canDoIap = true
productID: {(
    "CricketCrazy.AdRemoval"
)}
request: <SKProductsRequest: 0x17063e740>
Purchase
inside paymentQueue Fuction
.Restored
tapBlasts: 0
inside paymentQueue Fuction
.Restored
2015-01-14 08:50:29.497 CricketCrazy[21576:2483010] <SKPaymentQueue: 0x17401d330>: Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions
tapBlasts: 0
inside productRequest function
restoring = false
inside paymentQueue Fuction
```

Comment: I would add the transaction observer at app launch. This is an Apple suggested best practice. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510678/how-to-test-skpaymenttransactionstatedeferred/27367749?noredirect=1#comment44325833_27367749 Perhaps you have unprocessed transactions in the queue?

Comment: yes it seems the problem is that there is unfinished transactions in queue. Perhaps there should be a way to clear the queue for testing.